# Summing the values in a list (python)

Tags: python, list, sum

Hi all I am having trouble trying to sum all the values in a list. I'm not sure if this is actually possible first.

```
dL= list(csv.reader(input))
sL = dL [14247:14611]
a = [row[5] for row in sL[1:]] 
print a
```

This code is what I have so far and produces the result

```
['5.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1.6', '4.4', '14.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '95.6', '63.6', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '9.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '20.2', '14.4', '1.6', '0.0', '7.6', '2.4', '0.0', '11.4', '0.0', '79.4', '60.4', '27.2', '', '1.8', '0.0', '0.0', '29.6', '67.6', '2.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '14.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '', '3.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '6.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '11.8', '2.4', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.4', '16.8', '8.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '2.6', '27.2', '77.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '9.2', '2.6', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1.6', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '6.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '37.8', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

The above list is not typed but produced by the function code. Does this affect the result?

Can anyone please assist me in showing me how to solve this problem and sum all these values in a code from this list. I believe I will have to join string to do so but am unsure. Can you please inform me whether this is possible to sum all these values of the list and if so how can I do it?

EDIT:

```
THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP GUYS
```

Comment: Note: The list has empty strings. Cannot be easily seen from this long list.

Comment: Regarding EDIT: Delete the `a = ['']; ` and print the calculated sum not `a`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `math.fsum` for a more accurate sum:

```
>>> nums = ['5.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1.6', '4.4', '14.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '95.6', '63.6', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '9.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '20.2', '14.4', '1.6', '0.0', '7.6', '2.4', '0.0', '11.4', '0.0', '79.4', '60.4', '27.2', '', '1.8', '0.0', '0.0', '29.6', '67.6', '2.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '14.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '', '3.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '6.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '11.8', '2.4', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.4', '16.8', '8.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '2.6', '27.2', '77.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '9.2', '2.6', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1.6', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '6.8', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '37.8', '0.2', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
>>> from math import fsum
>>> fsum(float(n or 0.0) for n in nums)
749.8
```

As opposed to

```
>>> sum(float(n or 0.0) for n in nums)
749.8000000000003
```

Using your code,  a more efficient way of doing it without saving the whole file into memory at once:

```
from itertools import islice
dL= csv.reader(input)
sL = islice(dL, 14247+1, 14611)    
a = [row[5] for row in sL] 
print fsum(float(n or 0.0) for n in a)
```

Comment: This is a nice code however my list is not actually typed by hand but created using the function. Will this result still work? I am trying to use the code but it doesnt work. Do i have to type the list out manually?

Comment: @user2423678 you may be required to use other parts of the list in your code, so then it's best to store it all in memory at once, however you didn't give any information regarding that in the question statement

Comment: How would i store that in memory as you say in order to use the list to sum the values?

Comment: @user2423678 I was referring to your original code which stores the whole list in memory

Answer (score 2):

You can sum all numbers with `sum` but need to convert the strings to floats before and check for empty strings:

```
sum(float(x) for x in a if x)
```

Comment: this doesn't work since the input has empty strings, try `float('')`

Comment: There's an `if` in the comprehension (now).

Comment: Works for me `a = [''];sum(float(x) for x in a if x)` gives `0.0`.

Comment: in terms of this the list isnt actually typed it is produced by the function. Does this still work because it doesnt work for me

Comment: It does not matter how the list comes about. As long as `a` is a list of strings it works, no matter if you type it in, read it from a file or use some other way to generate it.

Comment: my code does still not work this is what i have with open('4083_1800_Data.csv', 'rU') as input: dL= list(csv.reader(input)) sL = dL [14247:14611] a = [row[5] for row in sL[1:]] a = ['']; sum(float(x) for x in a if x) print a can you see where it is wrong at all?

Comment: Please delete the `a= ['']`. This was just to proof that a list with only one empty string produces a sum of zero. You need to use the list `a` with the data you read from the file to feed to `res = sum(float(x) for x in a if x)`.
Then you can print the result with `print(res)`.

Comment: Thanks so much Mike. That makes sense because you cant use the same variable letter twice with different constants because it will not work. This makes much more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, map(float, filter(lambda x:x!='', a)))
```

Comment: A rather convoluted form of: `sum(map(float, filter(None, a)))` ?